# joining tables in laravel elequent

Tags: php, laravel-5

how can i join those two tables in laravel elequent  and make them as one table ?

Table 1(base info ) :

```
id  baseId   Site_ID  region    city        address
1     123      321     west    wakanda      street2
```

Table 2(basecounts) :

```
base_id     First     Second   third  
1            54          52     51
```

i have those two models idk if they are correct or not :

```
class base extends Model
{
    public function Counts() {
    return $this->hasOne(CountInBase::class, 'base_id');
}

}

class CountInBase extends Model
{
    public function bases() {
        return $this->belongsTo(base::class ,'base_id','id');
    }
}
```

in controller i am trying to make this query but i am not getting the expacted result  , i am just getting the results of the first table :

```
$data = base::where('region' ,'=' ,'west')->with(['Counts'])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `Counts` data like this:

```
foreach($data as $base) {
    // $base->Counts->First;
}
```

Comment: Can you please give feedback on the answer?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to join two or more different tables as a table you must use join

```
 $integratedTable = \DB::table('bases')
        ->join('basecounts', 'bases.id', '=', 'basecounts.base_id')
        ->get();

 return $integratedTable;

/*
[
    {
    "id": 1,
    "baseId": 1,
    "Site_ID": 1,
    "region": "west",
    "city": "wakanda",
    "address": "street2",
    "base_id": 1,
    "First": 54,
    "Second": 52,
    "third": 51,

    }
]
```

in mysql there are different ways to join two or more tables:

Inner Join

Left Join

Right Join

Union

Cross Join or Cartesian Product

Self Join

FULL OUTER JOIN

and Laravel supported them. You Can see it's document [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#joins)

Comment: Didn't you have your answer?